# Calculating the value to know the trend in a set of numeric values

Tags: r

I have a requirement where I have set of numeric values for example: 2, 4, 2, 5, 0

As we can see in above set of numbers the trend is mixed but since the latest number is 0, I would consider the value is getting DOWN. Is there any way to measure the trend (either it is getting up or down).

Is there any R package available for that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: This question is very broad. There are many techniques that may be applicable depending on the assumption that are appropriate for the data. Questions about statistical methods go to CrossValidated but all what a migration will do is cause even more downvotes I think.

Comment: What I want is some thing like slope or line of best fit (including outliers). I want to get a number that shows me the degree sales from a specific customer is going down (assuming each number in vector representing a customer share in our sales). For example 5, 0, 3, 2, 3 will produce higher value than 5, 4, 3, 2, 2. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Another example 5, 4, 1, 0 should produce a number with higher degree of downwards slope than 5, 4, 0, 0. Because in first case we need to be more concerned to bring our customer back because we started loosing him recently. While second customer though has 0 sales but it is same for last two months and it might be a relatively a bit more difficult to bring him back.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your vector is c(2, 4, 2, 5, 0) and you want to know last value (increasing, constant or decreasing), then you could use diff function with a lag of 1. Below is an example.

```r
MyVec <- c(2, 4, 2, 5, 0)
Lagged_vec <- diff(MyVec, lag=1)
if(MyVec[length(MyVec)]<0){
   print("Decreasing")}
else if(MyVec[length(MyVec)]==0){
   print("Constant")}
else {print("Increasing")}
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.